# How does binary-to-text encoding algorithm work?

Tags: ascii

Gnupg allows one to convert binary secret key to plain-text ASCII. How does this work? It's obviously not as simple as taking 7-bit chunks and mapping those to ASCII characters:

```
user@T60:~/.gnupg> xxd -b secring.gpg | sed 's/[[:xdigit:]]*: //;s/.\{8\}$//;s/ //g' | head -3
100101010000001110111110000001000101000111101001
010011011001011000000001000010000000000011101100
000011001010111010000001101010000001100111111010
user@T60:~/.gnupg> gpg --armor --output - --export 'Test' | head -5
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v2.0.18 (GNU/Linux)

mQENBFHpTZYBCADsDK6BqBn6rqwtEC66Po/8XCEcObCjCfhSVk3iuj4MVfted7eq
1x0sUfPs0ORVQJTiXDJ7mzzMhYIHYP4e8njObiT4B+TRas48toEnDS3605wDp9yX
user@T60:~/.gnupg>
```

Could somebody explain this based on my binary stream?

Comment: My guess is ROT13.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13

Comment: @Gilbert Le Blanc It's Base64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a mistake in initial question. I should have used "pubring.gpg" as an input for `xxd` not "secring.gpg". The binary to text encoding used by gpg is Base64. This means that 24 first bits would be 100101(dec 37), 010000(dec 16), 001110(dec 14) and 111110(dec 62) and they would encode to 'l', 'Q', 'O' and '+' accordingly. Sorry for providing wrong information in the initial question.